# Why I am unable to send email with excel attachment using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I think the problem is in parameter `server=...`  what should I put here?

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders


def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server=r'\\myserver\User\name\PythonProject\'):
  assert type(send_to)==['sendto@.com']
  assert type(files)==['File Name.xlsx']
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['From'] = "sendfrom@.com"
  msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
  msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
  msg['Subject'] = subject
  msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
  for f in files:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload( open(files,"rb").read() )
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)
  smtp = smtplib.SMTP('1.1.1.1: 25')
  smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
  smtp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has number of problems.

- The default value of `server` in the function signature

  - the string ends with `\'`, which escapes the closing quote: remove it or escape it (the "r" prefix escapes the backslashes *inside* the string, but the terminal backslash is interpreted as escaping the closing quote and so *outside* the string)
  - `server` is not used in the function
- Using a [mutable default value](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) like `files=[]` is usually a bad idea; better to use `files=None` and check the value in your code before trying to iterate over it
- the `assert` statements don't work.

  - use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) rather than `type` to check object types
- `part.set_payload( open(files,"rb").read() )` is trying to open the *list* of files, it only needs to open the current file in the loop: `open(f, ...)`

Here is a "fixed" version of the code

```
def send_mail(
    send_from,
    send_to,
    subject,
    text,
    files=None,
    server=r"\\myserver\User\name\PythonProject\\",
):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)
    assert isinstance(files, list)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = "sendfrom@.com"
    msg["To"] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg["Date"] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
    if files is not None:
        for f in files:
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(open(f, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header(
                "Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f)
            )   
        msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('1.1.1.1:25')
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```